# Dificultades con claves foraneas

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla User con estas variables:

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('second_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('provincia')->nullable();
        $table->string('localidad')->nullable();
        $table->string('direccion')->nullable();
        $table->string('telefono');
        $table->date('fecha_nacimiento');
        $table->string('dni');
        $table->boolean('vehiculo')->default(false);
        $table->string('foto')->default('anonimo.jpg');
        $table->boolean('activado')->default(false); // Se marca aqui como falso y ya se pone automaticamente así al hacer el formulario.
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Y una tabla de nombre Inscribe, que uso para indicar que un usuario se ha apuntado a una oferta de trabajo:

```
    Schema::create('inscribes', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->unsignedInteger('oferta_id');
        $table->foreign('oferta_id')->references('id')->on('ofertas');
        $table->boolean('seleccionado')->default(false);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

La tabla Inscribe se relaciona con User mediante esta relación:

```
public function usuario(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Y aqui tengo la vista con los datos de la inscripción del usuario, que la llamo $i.

```
<div class="card card-01">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url($i->usuario()->ruta())}}" alt="{{$i->usuario()->name}}"/>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title text-center">{{$i->usuario()->name}} {{$i->usuario()->second_name}}</h2>
        <span class="badge badge-danger badge-cat">DNI: {{ $i->usuario()->dni }}</span>
        <span class="badge badge-danger badge-cat">Telefono: {{ $i->usuario()->telefono }}</span>
        <hr>
        @if(!$i->seleccionado)
            <a href="{{ url('/inscrito_seleccion/'.$i->id) }}" class="btn btn-course btn-block">Confirmar contratación</a>
            <a href="{{ url('/eliminar_seleccion/'.$i->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Denegar contratación</a>
        @else
            <p class="btn btn-success btn-block">El usuario fue seleccionado para este trabajo</a>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Pero me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien me sale mensaje de error para cosas como `$i->usuario()->id`.
¿Como logro acceder al usuario desde la inscripción?

Más datos: Esta es la función que convoca la vista:

```
public function elegidos(Oferta $oferta){
        $inscritos=Inscribe::all()->where('oferta_id',$oferta->id);

        if(count($inscritos))
            return view('listas.inscritos',compact('inscritos','oferta'));
        else
            return back()->with('message',['danger','Por ahora nadie se ha inscrito a esta oferta de trabajo']);
    }
```

Y antes de llegar a dicha vista hay que pasar por esta otra:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1 class="text-center text-mute"><u>Usuarios inscritos a {{$oferta->titulo}}:</u></h1>
    <div class="pl-5 pr-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            @forelse($inscritos as $i)
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @include('listas.interno.datos_inscripcion')
                    </div>
            @empty
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <h1>No hay nadie inscrito a esta oferta actualmente</h1>
                </div>
            @endforelse
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Por cierto, he descubierto esto.
Esta es la migración de la tabla Oferta.php:

```
    Schema::create('ofertas', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('titulo');
        $table->text('descripcion');
        $table->string('empresa');
        $table->string('sector');
        $table->date('fecha_limite');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Y este es la función con la que la tabla Inscribe se relaciona con Oferta:

```
public function oferta(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Oferta::class);
}
```

Si pongo `{{$i->oferta->titulo}}`, todo sale bien.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si pruebo a escribir `{{$i->usuario->name}}`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora no funciona.

Comment: añade como estas enviando la informacion desde el controlador

Comment: @AlfredoPaz Hecho.

Comment: este método esta mal escrito a lo que yo se $inscritos=Inscribe::all()->where('oferta_id',$oferta->id);

Comment: debería ser así $inscritos=Inscribe::where('oferta_id',$oferta->id)->get();

Comment: Pues si, veo que eso tambien funciona.

Comment: Pero mi problema persiste. Tengo una variable $i de un objeto de la tabla Inscribe, ¿como accedo al nombre del usuario? $i->usuario()->name no me funciona.

Comment: Me sale esto: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bolsa\resources\views\listas\interno\datos_inscripcion.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bolsa\resources\views\listas\interno\datos_inscripcion.blade.php)

Comment: tiene en link en tu modelo user `User`? ejemplo tienes el metodo `public function event()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('inscribes'); 
    }`

Comment: @MiguelOsorio public function inscripciones(){
        return $this->hasMany(Inscribe::class);
    }

Comment: Este es el metodo con el que la tabla User se relaciona con la tabla Inscribe.

Comment: He editado mi comentario para incluir más información.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una "solución".

Esta es la nueva función que enlaca Inscribe con User:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Adapto la vista a la nueva función:

```
<div class="card card-01">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url($i->user->ruta())}}" alt="{{$i->user->name}}"/>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title text-center">{{$i->user->name}} {{$i->user->second_name}}</h2>
        <span class="badge badge-danger badge-cat">DNI: {{ $i->user->dni }}</span>
        <span class="badge badge-danger badge-cat">Telefono: {{ $i->user->telefono }}</span>
        <hr>
        @if(!$i->seleccionado)
            <a href="{{ url('/inscrito_seleccion/'.$i->id) }}" class="btn btn-course btn-block">Admitir al usuario en el trabajo</a>
            <a href="{{ url('/inscrito_eliminar/'.$i->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Rechazar al usuario</a>
        @else
            <p class="btn btn-success btn-block">El usuario ha sido admitido en el trabajo</p>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Vaya con este caprichoso programa!
¿Hay algun modo de poder darle a la función para enlazar la clave foranea el nombre que desee?